# JqueryMobile page initialization function

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I am using a master page on a JQuery-Mobile app that have few controller , and I want to set up a Javascript call to an initialize function on every page even when it loads through Ajax,

Iam sure there are few ways to do that, but whats the best approach and what would be the alternative to $(document).ready  when the page is called through ajax instead of being directly loaded without that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery Mobile Docs - Events](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html)

```
$('div').live('pageshow',function(event, ui){
  alert('This page was just hidden: '+ ui.prevPage);
});
```

or

```
$(document).bind("pageshow".function(){
  // initialize code here
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I read that but their examples were confusing and they mixed few things together , also in your code there should be comma instead or dot between ("pageshow",function() )
' $(document).bind("pageshow",function(){
  // initialize code here
});'

Comment: Hi, I am facing some problem in initializing JS code, i tried pageshow event but on each visit call to JS Init Code increases, ex. on third visit to page, this method get called three times on fourth visit it get called four times, my question is here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724959/asp-net-mvc3-jquery-mobile-pages-ajax-code-binding-using-pageinit-event

Answer (score 2):

takepara's answer is correct, but...

If you want to modify the content of the page you will have to bind earlier.

Take a look at `beforepagecreate` event.
If your handler for this event returns false, then no JQM widgets and styles will be applied and you can work with it manually.

Comment: ya thanks that was another thing that confused me, as I was trying to understand when that issue will be present, I thought you need to early bind always, appreciate your help