# ASP.NET MVC3 jQuery mobile page's Ajax code binding using PageInit event

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

We are writing JQueryMobile application using ASP.NET MVC3 + JqueryMobile RC1. 
Few pages have their own Ajax methods which we call using jQuery code (`$.getJSON()`) method.

To invoke these in Ajax calls we do click event bindings inside "pageinit" event of jquery-mobile as mentioned here(http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc1/docs/api/events.html). 
But, call to method binded to pageinit get increased +1 by each visit to the page. e.g. if i visit again to my page using back button or from any other link, visit it again, pageinit method called twice, and any code written inside pageinit executed two times...these keep on increasing with each visit to page.

Which event should we use to bind events. and it should be called only once on page load?

Edit:-
We want default AJAX behavior of JQM and we have kept AjaxEnabled to true.

Sample source Code(you may repro this issue by creating new MVC3 APP and replacing below three .cshtml with given code:-

My _Layout.cshtml:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc1/jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
            $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = true;
        });
    </script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0rc1/jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.min.js"></script>
    @RenderSection("HeaderScripts", required: false)
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="@ViewBag.DivTitle">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>
                @ViewBag.Title
            </h1>
             <a href="/Home/About" data-role="Button" data-icon="info"  data-iconpos="notext">About</a>
              <a href="/Home/Index" data-role="Button" data-icon="home"  data-iconpos="notext">Home</a>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content" id="DivContent">
            @RenderBody()
            @RenderSection("BodyScriptsSection", required: false)
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            @RenderSection("MobileFooter", required: false)
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Sample Index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    ViewBag.DivTitle = "HomeIndex";
}

@section BodyScriptsSection {
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $("#@ViewBag.DivTitle").live("pageshow", function () {
      alert ("PageShow Called - HomeIndex");
  });

      </script>
```

Sample AboutUS.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About Us";
    ViewBag.DivTitle = "AboutUS";

}

@section BodyScriptsSection {
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $("#@ViewBag.DivTitle").live("pageshow", function () {
          alert("PageShow Called - AboutUS");
      });

      </script>
```

Comment: I posted this problem in JQM forum http://forum.jquery.com/topic/binding-to-event-inside-div-page-keep-increasing-with-each-visit-using-ajax-navigation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you kill your handlers upon navigating away, something like this:

```
$("#@ViewBag.DivTitle").live("pagehide", function() {
    $("#@ViewBag.DivTitle").die("pageshow");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Paul. +1 for your good idea, It seem to solving my problem. Either I will choose this option or alternative suggested by Jasper to load all the .js in first page, hence, not requiring bind/die combination on each page, depending on which gives better perf.

Answer (score 1):

Using the jQuery Mobile framework, if you place a `<script>` inside the `<div data-role="page">` element it will be run each time the page is shown and if you are binding event handlers inside the code they will be bound each time the page is viewed as the DOM remains the same throughout site navigation.

Try moving the `@RenderSection("BodyScriptsSection", required: false)` statement to the bottom of the page, just before the closing `</body>` tag. That way the script will be included on every full-refresh (like if the user presses their refresh button) and if a user deep-links into your site; however it will not be run each time the page is gathered by jQuery Mobile's AJAX navigation.

You can also fix this issue by caching each page so it doesn't have to be gathered by the AJAX navigation on subsequent visits to the page. By default, jQuery Mobile Beta 3 and later (RC 1 at this time) remove pages from the DOM after they have been navigated away from by the user (event handlers bound are however not removed), this feature helps control the size of the DOM. To cache a page add `data-dom-cache="true"` to the `<div data-role="page">` element.

Comment: Thanks jasper, your answer nicely explains reason behind my problem and helped me in understanding it better. I tried data-dom-cache="true to <div data-role="page"> div, and kept BodyScriptsSection inside page div, it didn't fix my problem :( Also knowing abt removal of pageDiv on leaving page was good as I was worried abt heavy DOM of my app. I don't want to lose ajax navigation so moving script out of page-div don't help me either.

Comment: If your external script includes all the necessary JS for your site it can be loaded only once, which is where putting the external script include at the bottom of the page comes in (just before the closing `</body>` tag).

Comment: but in that case, I will have to load page without ajax, (with rel="external" in <a> tag, to get event binded at least once, my .js inlcude binding of .click events on load of page (with help of "pageshow" event.

Comment: You can use `.delegate()` or `.live()` to bind those events to elements that do not yet exist. That way you can load all your JS at the initial page-load and then the event handlers will bind themselves when the proper elements are added to the DOM.

Comment: Thanks jasper, is it good idea to load all the ajax .js combined inside <head> of the first page of mobile app? Or as and when page get created, load the .js specific to that page, which would give better perf from both case?

Comment: That depends on the size of your external JS file. Unless you have a seriously large amount of code for each page I would use one include. It would create less calls to the server for one. As far as performance, I notice a lot of developers do not minify their code, check-out HTML Compressor: http://code.google.com/p/htmlcompressor/.

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

**1. use one() instead of bind() or live()**
As long as the page is not dropped from the DOM, this should help. See [here](http://api.jquery.com/one/).

It says: "attach a handler to an event for an element. The handler is executed at most once per element."

Jquery Mobile uses it inside JQM too, probably for the same reason. So if you do like this:

`$('button').one('click', function () { do something });`

that should fire only once.

**2. Use data() to set a flag after event is fired**
Another idea would be to use data() to attach a flag to the page element or, as pages can be removed from the DOM, better attach it to the HTML or BODY element. These will stay...

I initiate scrollview on pages (hopefully once) like this:

```
$('div[data-role="page"]').live('pagebeforeshow.scroll', function(event){
     var $page = $(this);
     if ( $page.data('scrollable', 'Off') ) {
         $page.data('scrollable', 'On');
         scrollMe( $page ); // init
         }
      });
```

This would probably mean putting your function call outside of the actual page.

**EDIT:**

This also works for me using `attr`:

```
    // on pageinit - set global argument
    $('html').attr('fire-once', 'Off'); 

    $( '#your page' ).live( 'pageshow',function(event){
    if ( $('html').attr('fire-once') == 'Off' ) {
            $('html').attr('fire-once', 'On');
            // your button.bind.behavior here
            }
       });
```

This way you set "fire-once" on the HTML element, which will always stay the same in JQM while you load pages in and out. Only if you go to a page with data-rel="external", fire-once will be reset.

On your specified page you listen for pageshow, fire the function, that first changes fire-once to "On" and then adds your button binding.

Since fire-once is now turned "On", even with multiple bindings the if-statement will fail and you will only assign the button behavior once.

I'm using the same setup with a JQM-panel history-array, which I need to setup only once and only add entries on changePage once, too. The above works fine for me and should also serve your purpose.

Send me a message, if you want to see a live example.

Cheers,

Frequent

Comment: Yeah I like this even better than the live/die, forgot about this method, a lot more elegant.

Comment: Thx. But I afraid it won't serve my purpose, as I want if user click on button and tht btn make ajax call, if user click on it each time ajax call should be made. .one will defy this. My problem is on each ajax-visit to the page, .click get binded, so in second visit  single click cause 2 time execution of method binded to click.

Answer (score 0):

You could keep a variable `IsPageInitialized = false` for each page, bind events only if this variable is false and set it to true when you assign the event handlers.

Comment: This hack would be my last resort, but this behavior makes me think that I am doing something wrong with the way this framework should be used with MVC3.

Answer (score 0):

You example code uses 'pageshow' rather than 'pageinit'. 'Pageinit' should work fine.

Comment: I tried both, it all behave same, I need to use once in page lifetime event like pagecreate,pageinit, and one which fires evry time page get show like pageshow, both type of event behave in same way

Answer (score -2):

It sounds like you might need to wrap your code in an `IsPostBack` check. For example:

```
void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        RegisterScriptHere();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

On a second reading, you may not be asking about the server side, if you are trying to do this on the client side, ignore my answer.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC doesn't have the concept of post-backs.