# JQuery Mobile Ajax Navigation in Single-Page Template

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile

We are developing JQuery Mobile app using RC1 + ASP.NET MVC3.
My question is:

Is Ajax based page navigation possible using single page template? (as mentioned here:
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc1/docs/pages/page-template.html )

I am keeping $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = true;   and using simple  I am able to navigate to different "Single page" of application. I have few event binding to be done in new page (which we usually do in $(document).ready()) event of jQuery, I tried to use pageinit, pageshow events of jQueryMobile as well as Ready() event, but these are simply not being called.

Many Thanks for any helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes AJAX based page navigation is supported when each of your `<div data-role="page">` elements are on different pages. On navigation, jQuery Mobile will find only the first `<div data-role="page">` element on the page, add it to the current DOM, and then animate it into view.

Make sure you are using `.delegate()` or `.live()` to bind your event handlers since the elements you are binding-to do not exist in the DOM until the user navigates to them. Here's an example:

```
$(document).delegate('[data-role="page"]', 'pageshow', function () {
    alert(this.id + ' --> pageshow');
});
```

If you are using the pushState feature that updates the URL to not include the hashes (e.g. www.mywebsite.com/index.html#/dir1/page2.html changes to www.mywebsite.com/dir1/page2.html) I would recommend writing all your custom JavaScript in an external `.js` file and including it on every page. This way if a user refreshes the browser or deep-links into your site they will get all the code for the experience you want them to have.

Documentation:

- Delegate: http://api.jquery.com/delegate

Comment: Thanks jasper, your explanation at first paragraph itself helped me in fixing the issue. I was already using the .live. I transferred the code to .click event binding to 'pagecreate' event and code of ajax call on each show event to 'pageshow', and it is working fine now.

Comment: Now I am stuck with different issue, I put all my JS code(which has some event binding inside pagecreate event and ajax call on pageshow event) in serpate .js file. I add this .js file from inside page-div. Now each time i visit this page using normal <a> tag, call to pagecreate and pageshow event keep on increasing by +1. and even though pageshow get called mutliple times,rest of the code written inside it do not get called. I previously explained this issue in separate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724959/asp-net-mvc3-jquery-mobile-pages-ajax-code-binding-using-pageinit-event

Comment: I added an answer to your other question ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7724959/asp-net-mvc3-jquery-mobile-pages-ajax-code-binding-using-pageinit-event ). In short, cache your pages in the DOM (`data-dom-cache="true"`) or move your custom JS code to the bottom of your HTML documents (outside the `<div data-role="page">` element). As the pages are not being cached they are gathered via AJAX each time they are requested and the JS code is being run on each visit (which will compound any `bind` statements you use even though the page is removed from the DOM after the user leaves it).

Answer (score 0):

You can link the second single page using a normal link, as explained here

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc1/docs/pages/page-links.html

Alternatively you can force a page loading using the changePage utility

```
$.mobile.changePage( 'secondPage.html', 'slide' );
```

which is documented here

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/methods.html